# JavaScript/JSON: Get unknown property of an object

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

If I have a JSON object like this:

```
{
    "message": {
        "name": { "stringLengthTooShort": "blub" }
    }
}
```

The name of the property (here) `stringLengthTooShort` is changing every time,
how could I simply just get the child property of `name` with JS?
At the moment I have `message.name` but how could I get now the child of it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if it's always the first property of `message.name`, you could do something like:

```
var keys = [];
for (var l in message.name) {
  if (message.name.hasOwnProperty(l)){
    keys.push(l);
  }
}
//=>first property value should now be in message.name[keys[0]]);
//  (its label is keys[0])
```

**Edit**: *nine years* after this answer all modern browsers support es20xx, so it's safe to use:

```js
const obj = {
    "message": {
        "name": { "stringLengthTooShort": "blub" }
    }
};

console.log(Object.keys(obj.message.name)[0]);
```