# How to access the value in key value pair when the key is a changing value?

Tags: json

I have this JSON data stored in variable `result`, now I want to access the value of `result.metadata.data.s1[1].lily` , however the key `Lily` is not known and it may change on server side, so I stored the key as a variable, like `var key1 = "Lily"`. How to access the value with this `var key1` ?

```
{
         "metadata":{

            "data":{
               "s1":[
                  {
                     "Lily":"chat",
                     "time":10
                  },
                  {
                     "Mancy":"chat1",
                     "time":10
                  },
                  {
                     "John":"chat2",
                     "time":10
                  }
               ],
               "s2":[
                  {
                     "Lan":"chat3",
                     "time":10
                  },
                  {
                     "Yoyo":"chat6",
                     "time":10
                  }
               ]
            }
         }

}
```

Comment: is `"chat"` always constant? Maybe that should be the key instead... that or create a `"your_key_is":"Yoyo"` thing so you can double-lookup the avlues.

Comment: no, "chat" is just come fake data I created here, and it is also uncertain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript/JSON: Get unknown property of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842280/javascript-json-get-unknown-property-of-an-object)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json/11922384#11922384

Comment: Is this JSON generated by you? if yes, why don't just: `{Name: "Lily", Action: "chat", time: 10}` ?

Comment: The json structured is already stable on server, so I have to cope with that.

Comment: thanks for the above links!

Answer (score 1):

If you always know it's the first item in the list, bracket notation should work fine.

```
result.metadata.data.s1[0][key1];
```

If you're not sure where it falls, then the `[0]` won't always be correct, and you'll have to iterate through all of the items in the `result.metadata.data.s1` array to find it.

Your code above is getting the second item in the list, at index `[1]`, and the key there is not "Lily", it's "Mancy".

[Here's a codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rEsgG)

Comment: `data.metadata.data.s1[0]` is an `object` not an `array`, you cant access the value this way

Comment: @Blake- Right, `data.metadata.data.s1` is the array. `data.metadata.data.s1[0]` is the first object in that array. It contains the "Lily" key.

Comment: Working codepen added. Bracket notation seems to work fine, unless I've missed something.

Comment: hmm, my mistake, why I have this impression that value in object can be accessed that way... never mind.